# PHP error reporting off

Tags: php

I am getting this error:

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session
>   cache limiter - headers already sent

how do I completly turn off error reporting from my server, currently the php. ini file has:

> error_reporting                     = Off   display_errors
>   = Off

but still shows this error.

Comment: Why don't you just fix it? Hey doctor it is a nail in my leg - nah, we won't remove it, let's continue living with analgesic

Comment: @zerkms is absolutely right. Ignoring errors like this may well just break your site in unexpected ways.

Comment: Read the canonical answer regarding this topic: [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Answer (score 2):

1. Check the php load the right php.ini file. use phpinfo() to see the loaded one.
2. Grep the code to find if there is some code like `ini_set('display_errors', true)` that override the php.ini settings.
3. Besides of doing the above 2, you should fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

> how do I completly turn off error reporting from my server

There is one problem. **Turning error messages off won't make your sessions work.**
So, despite of your attitude with error reporting, you have to fix that error anyway.  Fix, not gag.

As for the displaying errors, keep `error_reporting` always at max and turn only `display_errors` off if it's production server